# Xamarin.Essentials DeviceDisplay class in .NET6 MAUI

Tags: maui

Xamarin.Essentials' class DeviceDisplay.KeepScreenOn does not have an equivalent in .NET6 MAUI as yet.

Is this intentional? or should I be using something else to stop the screen timing out?

Comment: Question partially obsolete now. Only matters if someone is explicitly trying to access `...Essentials.DeviceDisplay` class, which has been moved. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

`DeviceDisplay` class is now in namespace `Microsoft.Maui.Devices`.
This namespace is automatically referenced in new Maui projects, so you may refer to simply as `DeviceDisplay`, without needing any `using ..;` statement.

Typical usage is described in [Device Display Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/display):

```cs
... DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width   // get Width in pixels.

// To keep screen on:
DeviceDisplay.Current.KeepScreenOn = true;
```

When accessing multiple properties, it is convenient to copy to a local variable:

```cs
IDeviceDisplay devinfo = DeviceDisplay.Current;
// OR if just want MainDisplayInfo:
DisplayInfo display = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo;
```

Comment: Where should I use it? On Android it fails with :

System.NullReferenceException: 'The current Activity can not be detected. Ensure that you have called Init in your Activity or Application class.'